# How Should I Be Accessing My Server?

Tags: server

I'm really new to the whole Ubuntu thing, I've been and still am a windows user, for my windows server I would just use RDC (remote desktop connection) and be done with it, as in apps are still running when I close RDC.

For Ubuntu I've been using SSH but as soon as I close it anything I've started ends. Also while I prefer a GUI it seems that most stuff in the Ubuntu is terminal based and I'm ok learning this.

I'm currently running the standard version of Ubuntu 16.04 LTS

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's what I do on a daily basis to remote into an Ubuntu Server.

On Windows machine: Install PuTTY and x11vnc viewer

On Ubuntu Server: Install ssh and x11vnc

From Windows PC:

1 - Launch PuTTY

2 - Connect to IP via ssh

3 - At the terminal run this command:

```
sudo x11vnc -display :0 -auth guess
```

Or you may need to be root

```
su -
```

then

```
x11vnc -display :0 -auth guess
```

Once x11vnc is running via terminal continue to next step...

4 - Launch x11vnc viewer on the Windows machince
5 - Enter the IP address of the Ubuntu Server and voila you're now looking at the GUI desktop of your Ubuntu Server.

Good Luck and Enjoy!

Comment: To me it seems like I dont need the sudo for this command

Answer (score 4):

> For Ubuntu I've been using SSH but as soon as I close it anything I've started ends

Have a look at the command [nohup](http://linux.die.net/man/1/nohup) and the "&" at the end of a command. You can use those for commands and scripts your want to keep running when you exit a shell.

As an alternative we also have muliplexers that can create a session that is kept alive when exiting the shell. [screen](https://www.rackaid.com/blog/linux-screen-tutorial-and-how-to/) and [tmux](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/tmux) (here is an [comparison](https://www.wikivs.com/wiki/screen_vs_tmux)) are pretty famous in that regard.

By the way: if you like that kind of setup ... a remote desktop connection is also possible for Ubuntu: [Remmina](http://www.remmina.org/wp/) is the default client; it just needs a bit of configuring on the client and server.

Comment: There is also a user friendly text-based window manager based on GNU screen: [byobu](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Byobu)